# Android: application crashes on Picture.createFromStream()

Tags: android, image

My app displays a series of pictures.  For memory reasons, I want to serialize these pictures when they are not in use.  The serialization seems to work (doesn't throw exceptions or crash), but the application crashes on my Picture.createFromStream() call.  I can't find anything informative in the LogCat output, nor does the failed call throw a Throwable.  Any advice?

```
12-20 10:48:37.121: WARN/InputManagerService(53): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@438abe88
12-20 10:48:37.132: DEBUG/dalvikvm(53): threadid=17: bogus mon 1+0>0; adjusting
12-20 10:48:50.901: DEBUG/dalvikvm(238): GC freed 15257 objects / 1725344 bytes in 99ms
12-20 10:50:26.912: DEBUG/dalvikvm(238): GC freed 29 objects / 1200 bytes in 56ms
12-20 10:51:03.661: INFO/DEBUG(28): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
12-20 10:51:03.661: INFO/DEBUG(28): Build fingerprint: 'generic/sdk/generic/:1.6/Donut/20842:eng/test-keys'
12-20 10:51:03.661: INFO/DEBUG(28): pid: 238, tid: 238  >>> com. <<<
12-20 10:51:03.661: INFO/DEBUG(28): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr 00000004
12-20 10:51:03.661: INFO/DEBUG(28):  r0 00000004  r1 00000000  r2 00000004  r3 00299b98
12-20 10:51:03.661: INFO/DEBUG(28):  r4 00000000  r5 00000000  r6 00000001  r7 00299b00
12-20 10:51:03.661: INFO/DEBUG(28):  r8 00299ac0  r9 00000000  10 66616374  fp 00299b60
12-20 10:51:03.661: INFO/DEBUG(28):  ip ac1285f4  sp bef065f0  lr ac06fc10  pc afb04408  cpsr 60000010
12-20 10:51:03.771: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #00  pc 00004408  /system/lib/libcutils.so
12-20 10:51:03.771: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #01  lr ac06fc10  /system/lib/libsgl.so
12-20 10:51:03.771: INFO/DEBUG(28): stack:
12-20 10:51:03.781: INFO/DEBUG(28):     bef065b0  00299b00  [heap]
12-20 10:51:03.781: INFO/DEBUG(28):     bef065b4  ac07b4f8  /system/lib/libsgl.so
12-20 10:51:03.781: INFO/DEBUG(28):     bef065b8  00000000  
12-20 10:51:03.781: INFO/DEBUG(28):     bef065bc  00616374  
12-20 10:51:03.781: INFO/DEBUG(28):     bef065c0  00299b78  [heap]
12-20 10:51:03.781: INFO/DEBUG(28):     bef065c4  ac038f48  /system/lib/libsgl.so
12-20 10:51:03.781: INFO/DEBUG(28):     bef065c8  00299ac0  [heap]
12-20 10:51:03.781: INFO/DEBUG(28):     bef065cc  00000001  
12-20 10:51:03.781: INFO/DEBUG(28):     bef065d0  00299b60  [heap]
12-20 10:51:03.781: INFO/DEBUG(28):     bef065d4  00299b78  [heap]
12-20 10:51:03.791: INFO/DEBUG(28):     bef065d8  00000000  
12-20 10:51:03.791: INFO/DEBUG(28):     bef065dc  00000001  
12-20 10:51:03.791: INFO/DEBUG(28):     bef065e0  00299b00  [heap]
12-20 10:51:03.791: INFO/DEBUG(28):     bef065e4  00299b78  [heap]
12-20 10:51:03.791: INFO/DEBUG(28):     bef065e8  df002777  
12-20 10:51:03.791: INFO/DEBUG(28):     bef065ec  e3a070ad  
12-20 10:51:03.791: INFO/DEBUG(28): #00 bef065f0  00000000  
12-20 10:51:03.791: INFO/DEBUG(28):     bef065f4  ac06fc10  /system/lib/libsgl.so
12-20 10:51:03.791: INFO/DEBUG(28):     bef065f8  bef06647  [stack]
12-20 10:51:03.791: INFO/DEBUG(28):     bef065fc  00000001  
12-20 10:51:03.801: INFO/DEBUG(28):     bef06600  00000070  
12-20 10:51:03.801: INFO/DEBUG(28):     bef06604  afe0ea00  /system/lib/libc.so
12-20 10:51:03.801: INFO/DEBUG(28):     bef06608  00299b00  [heap]
12-20 10:51:03.801: INFO/DEBUG(28):     bef0660c  afe0ed94  /system/lib/libc.so
12-20 10:51:03.801: INFO/DEBUG(28):     bef06610  00299b00  [heap]
12-20 10:51:03.801: INFO/DEBUG(28):     bef06614  000001b4  
12-20 10:51:03.801: INFO/DEBUG(28):     bef06618  000000dc  
12-20 10:51:03.801: INFO/DEBUG(28):     bef0661c  00002bcc  
12-20 10:51:03.801: INFO/DEBUG(28):     bef06620  bef06670  [stack]
12-20 10:51:03.811: INFO/DEBUG(28):     bef06624  afe0b70f  /system/lib/libc.so
12-20 10:51:03.811: INFO/DEBUG(28):     bef06628  afe39dd4  /system/lib/libc.so
12-20 10:51:03.811: INFO/DEBUG(28):     bef0662c  00299b00  [heap]
12-20 10:51:03.811: INFO/DEBUG(28):     bef06630  00299ae0  [heap]
12-20 10:51:03.811: INFO/DEBUG(28):     bef06634  00299ac0  [heap]
12-20 10:51:04.661: DEBUG/Zygote(30): Process 238 terminated by signal (11)
12-20 10:51:04.671: INFO/ActivityManager(53): Process com. (pid 238) has died.
12-20 10:51:04.691: INFO/WindowManager(53): WIN DEATH: Window{43899ae8 
12-20 10:51:04.701: INFO/WindowManager(53): WINDOW DIED during motion dispatch: 
12-20 10:51:04.761: WARN/UsageStats(53): Unexpected resume of com.android.launcher while already resumed in 
12-20 10:51:04.791: WARN/WindowManager(53): Requested window android.os.BinderProxy@437913d8 does not exist
12-20 10:51:04.791: WARN/WindowManager(53): java.lang.RuntimeException
12-20 10:51:04.791: WARN/WindowManager(53):     at com.android.server.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:7767)
12-20 10:51:04.791: WARN/WindowManager(53):     at com.android.server.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:7759)
12-20 10:51:04.791: WARN/WindowManager(53):     at com.android.server.WindowManagerService.removeWindow(WindowManagerService.java:1359)
12-20 10:51:04.791: WARN/WindowManager(53):     at com.android.server.WindowManagerService.dispatchPointer(WindowManagerService.java:4078)
12-20 10:51:04.791: WARN/WindowManager(53):     at com.android.server.WindowManagerService.access$1200(WindowManagerService.java:127)
12-20 10:51:04.791: WARN/WindowManager(53):     at com.android.server.WindowManagerService$InputDispatcherThread.process(WindowManagerService.java:5356)
12-20 10:51:04.791: WARN/WindowManager(53):     at com.android.server.WindowManagerService$InputDispatcherThread.run(WindowManagerService.java:5264)
12-20 10:51:04.832: WARN/InputManagerService(53): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 238 uid 10023
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a crash in native code, and therefore qualifies as a platform bug. Very similar stacktraces appear in bug reports [7468](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7468) and [2535](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2535).

Am afraid you will have to find a workaround fairly blindly. For starters, how many times do you draw to the Canvas between beginRecording() and endRecording()? How big is a typical serialized file?

Comment: The number of times I draw to the canvas varies from 10ish to a few hundred.  The crash occurs anytime I try to read a picture, it never succeeds.  The pictures from about 1000bbytes to about 30000bytes.

Comment: What size is the bitmap attached to the Canvas?  Can you post a small repro project?